# Height of a rotated ellipse

Tags: conic-sections, rotations

If I have an ellipse, it is easy to find its height, twice the length of the major axis. But if the ellipse is rotated a certain number of degrees, how do you find the vertical height from top to bottom?

Comment: The major axis *is* the height.  Are you thinking perhaps of the semi-major axis?

Comment: yes, sorry that's my mistake @BrianTung

Comment: In what form do you have the ellipse?  (i.e., how is it expressed)

Comment: x^2/a^2 + (y-b)^2/b^2=1 @BrianTung

Comment: What do you means for ''vertical height''? The major axis is the same after a rotation.

Comment: The vertical height would be the distance from the minimum of the function to the maximum of the function @EmilioNovati

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

An ellipse of center in the origin and the axis rotated by an angle $\theta$ has equation:
$$
\frac{(x\cos \theta+y\sin \theta)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y\cos \theta-x\sin \theta)^2}{b^2}=1
$$
that can be write as:
$$
Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2=1
$$
with $B^2-4AC<0$.
From this find:
$$
y=\dfrac{-Bx\pm\sqrt{B^2x^2-4C(Ax^2-1)}}{2C}
$$
and you have two equation of two semi-ellipses. Now find the maximum and minimum of these functions and the difference of the ordinates of these points is the searched height.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of a rotated ellipse is:
$$
\frac{(x\cos \theta+y\sin \theta)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(-x\sin \theta+y\cos \theta)^2}{b^2}=1
$$
Expand the equation:
$$
\left(\frac{\cos^2\theta}{a^2}+\frac{\sin^2\theta}{b^2}\right)x^2+2\cos\theta\sin\theta \left(\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{1}{b^2}\right)xy+\left(\frac{\sin^2\theta}{a^2}+\frac{\cos^2\theta}{b^2}\right)y^2=1
$$
This can be written as $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2=1$. Solve for x:
$$
x=\frac{-B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}
$$
The maximum and minimum values of $y$ are where there is only one value of $x$, i.e. where $B^2-4AC=0$, so we solve that equation:
$$
\left(2\cos\theta\sin\theta \left(\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{1}{b^2}\right)y-1\right)^2-4\left(\frac{\cos^2\theta}{a^2}+\frac{\sin^2\theta}{b^2}\right)\left(\frac{\sin^2\theta}{a^2}+\frac{\cos^2\theta}{b^2}\right)y^2=0
$$
$$
a^2+b^2-2y^2-(a^2-b^2)\cos2\theta=0
$$
$$
y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(a^2+b^2-(a^2-b^2)\cos2\theta\right)}
$$
Finally, the height of the ellipse is twice this distance, $2y$:
$$
\sqrt{2\left(a^2+b^2-(a^2-b^2)\cos2\theta\right)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The height is expressed by *y*. Extract *y* in terms of *x*, using the equation of the rotated ellipse, and then remember what you were taught in school about finding the maximum and minimum of a function...

Comment: How would the function of the rotated ellipse be expressed?

Comment: @Ryan: You are familiar with the general quadratic equation describing [conic sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section), right ? $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$. If $B\neq0$, the conic is [rotated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix). If either *D* or *E* is non-zero, its center does not lie in the origin. And if $\Delta=B^2-4AC<0$, the conic is an ellipse, assuming the equation is irreducible $($otherwise, the conic is degenerate$)$. So just solve for *y*.